# Expand all Threads (Conversations)

Tags: outlook-365

Is there a way to expand all threads/conversations by default in Outlook for Web (Office 365)? To be clear: I do NOT have an Outlook application installed on my laptop. This is the Web Outlook. I'm finding it hard to tell if an e-mail reply came into a mail I've already read since they are threaded but collapsed.

I can't find anything here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-more-about-outlook-on-the-web-adbacbab-fe59-4259-a550-6cb7f85f19ec

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a setting to expand the tree of conversations literally in Outlook Web. But you can disable the thread-view completely and hence get a better overview of the timeline of incoming emails. Maybe that helps already?

The switch to "Show each message separately" is here in the settings:

[image: Outlook settings]